# query with unicode character in ormlite is not giving required result

Tags: android, sqlite, cjk, ormlite

I am using ormlite for my application in android. I want to run a query with chinese string like

```
QueryBuilder<Hotel, Integer> qb = daoHotelObject.queryBuilder();
Where<Hotel,Integer> where=qb.where();
where.eq("hotel_name", pHotelName);
where.and();
where.between("hotel_avg_price", minRange,maxRange);
PreparedQuery<Hotel> pq = qb.prepare();
List<Hotel> serachListHotels = daoHotelObject.query(pq);
```

Where `pHotelName` is a Chinese string but the `serachListHotels` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [unit test](http://ormlite.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ormlite/ormliteAndroidTest/src/com/j256/ormlite/android/AndroidUnicodeTest.java?view=markup) works fine for me in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).  It does something like the following:

```
TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Foo.class);
Dao<Foo, Object> dao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Foo.class);
Foo foo = new Foo();
String unicodeString = "上海";
foo.stuff = unicodeString;
assertEquals(1, dao.create(foo));

QueryBuilder<Foo, Object> qb = dao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().eq(Foo.STUFF_FIELD_NAME, unicodeString);
List<Foo> results = qb.query();
assertEquals(1, results.size());
assertEquals(unicodeString, results.get(0).stuff);
```

This seems to be working fine.  Is there anything that you are doing differently?

Comment: Thanks for response i tried it with select args but it is not working.上海 this is the string that i am using and the where clause is where.eq("city_name",上海)

Comment: I have also tried it with hardcode string then it is working fine but the problem is the when i debug it the value of pCity comes is %E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7 something and then the query gives no record...